# How globally accurate is Python's time.time function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, time

I'm trying to measure the total time of a one-way trip UDP multicast. I have a device sending out a message on the multicast group every half second, and I have another device listening. I want to measure how long that takes, so I had the idea of taking a timestamp on the send side with time.time(), sending it as the message, and then subtracting that from the timestamp at the other end when the message is received.

However, I'm getting some negative numbers. I think that some of this has to do with decimal accuracy, which is something I'm still figuring out, but it is making me ask the question:

How *globally* accurate is time.time()? Will time.time() be the same down to the millisecond or microsecond for the same instant on two different devices?

Some code:

Sender:

```
import time
import decimal

[... socket setup ...]

current = str(decimal.Decimal(time.time()))
socket.sendto(current, ...)
```

Receiver:

```
import time

[... socket setup ...]

stamp = sock.recv(10240)
current = time.time()
diff = current - stamp

# stamp should be positive...
```

Edit: this is not a duplicate. That high-precision question has to do with relative precision, I'm asking about global precision (precision between devices). A device may be precise to the microsecond relative to itself, but be on a different second than another machine.

**Edit 2**: It seems that my actual question is, how globally accurate are Unix clocks?

Comment: Please remove the duplicate flag, this is not a duplicate.

Comment: In which case the answer is surely "not at all". How could it be? Python itself doesn't keep time, it just uses the clock of the system it runs on. If those clocks are inaccurate, there is nothing that Python could do about it.

Comment: All your machines should be synchronized with a stable time server. `ntp` can help you achieve this. That being said, I recommend you measure a round-trip so time is always measured on the same node.